# WHILE condition isn't retrieving data

Tags: php, database, mysqli, output, fetch

Hi so pretty much mysqli_query is going through and getting data I think. However, when trying to output the data later on it won't work. I have my query set to only retrieve data where the file name (form_'$last_id'.php) is the same value as a record in the 'Link' column of my link table in my database. No errors show and I have tripled check my mysqli tables and columns names. Here is the code:

**Fetching the data:**

```
<?php

$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "music_reviews_database";
$db_host = "localhost";

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

$filepath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$file = basename($filepath);

$q = mysqli_query($conn, 
    "SELECT album.Album, 
    artist.ArtistsName, 
    datereviewed.DateReviewed, 
    features.Features, 
    genre.Genre, 
    rating.Rating, 
    songname.SongName,
    link.Link,
    link.ID,
    comments.Comments
    FROM `link`
    INNER JOIN album ON album.ID = link.ID 
    INNER JOIN artist ON artist.ID = link.ID
    INNER JOIN datereviewed ON datereviewed.ID = link.ID
    INNER JOIN features ON features.ID = link.ID
    INNER JOIN genre ON genre.ID = link.ID
    INNER JOIN rating ON rating.ID = link.ID
    INNER JOIN comments ON comments.ID = link.ID
    INNER JOIN songname ON songname.ID = link.ID
    WHERE `Link`='$file'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($q); 
?>
```

**Outputting the data:**

```
   <h1>
       <?php   
       echo $row['SongName'];
       ?>
   </h1>
   <p> 
     <?php 
        echo '<b>', 'By: ', '</b>'. $row['ArtistsName'] . ' ft. ' . 
        $row['Features'] . '</br>';
        echo '<i>' . $row['Album'] . '</br>', '</br>', '</i>';
        echo '<b>', 'Genre: ', '</b>' . $row['Genre'] . '</br>', '</br>';
        echo '<b>', 'Rating: ', '</b>' . $row['Rating'] . '/5', '</br>', 
        '</br>';
        echo '<b>', 'Comments: ', '</b>', '</br>', '</br>' . 
        $row['Comments'];
      ?>    
   </p>
```

When echoing $file it shows up with the name form_130.php and in my database in my link table under the Link column there is the value form_130.php

Comment: I think the latest version of php only comes with mysqli. So mysqli_fetch_array replaces mysql_fetch_assoc. Tried it though and it came up with undefined function (referring to mysql_fetch_assoc).

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC)` it returns the results as an associative array

Comment: Just tried mysqli_fetch_array($q, MYSQLI_ASSOC); no errors but information still isn't being displayed.

Comment: can you please share your html file?

Comment: try this:  `$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC); $row = $rows[0];`

Comment: Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Ahh turns out the problem was actually because my id column in my tables weren't all the same because I had forget to send the song to my database. After fixing that and making sure the ID were aligned it works perfectly. Thank you though anyway